# Django 2 Implement a communication system between authenticated user

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a project to build a freelancing site something like Fiverr, I have implemented a `Gig Model`, so users can create `Gigs` and can orders `Gigs` from other users. I'm facing a very confusing issues for me as:

How Can I implement a communication system for user, when a user will make an order for a gig then he should be able to chat with the `seller` mean the Gig owner OR it should be similar to Fiverr communication.

Here's my model:

```
class Gig(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('GD', 'Graphic & Design'),
        ('DM', 'Digital Marketing'),
        ('WT', 'Writing & Translation'),
        ('VA', 'Video & Animation'),
        ('MA', 'Music & Audio'),
        ('PT', 'Programming & Tech'),
        ('FL', 'Fun & Lifestyle'),
    )

    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='gigs')
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Any resource, links and help will be very appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Have u tried https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat

Comment: Not yet, but let me take a look!

Comment: Although, I'm little bit confused about the workflow logic there, where I should implement this feature? Should it be before making an order OR after making an order?

Comment: I guess after the order or it depends on you! Logic can be applied to both scenarios.

Comment: Do you know about `Fiverr`?

Comment: No! But yes, just had a look.

Comment: Hi @IshwarJangid, have you found example of it's implementation?